# All the $k\times k$ minors determines the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose two $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ with the same $k\times k$ minors, that is, for each $1\leq i_1<\cdots<i_k\leq n$, 
$$\det\left(\begin{matrix}
a_{i_1i_1}&\cdots&a_{i_1i_k}\\
\vdots& \ddots& \vdots\\
a_{i_ki_1}&\cdots&a_{i_ki_k}\end{matrix}\right)=\det\left(\begin{matrix}
b_{i_1i_1}&\cdots&b_{i_1i_k}\\
\vdots& \ddots& \vdots\\
b_{i_ki_1}&\cdots&b_{i_ki_k}\end{matrix}\right),$$
can we deduce that $A=B$?

If $k=1$, it is obvious right.

If $k=n\geq 2$, it is obvious wrong.

However for other $k=2,\cdots,n-1$, I could not be affirmative...

Another related question is that for any $$m=\left(n\atop k\right)$$ scalars $a_1,\cdots,a_m$, is there exists a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ such that the minors (in dictionary order) are $a_1,\cdots,a_m$.

Comment: You should post your related question as a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$,
$B=0$. Then all the $2 \times 2$ minors are the same.

Answer (score 5):

If it is wrong for $k=n\ge 2$, it is certainly wrong for $k\ge 2$: Indeed, take two distinct $k\times k$ matrices with the same determinant and embed them in the upper left corner of an $n\times n$ matrix and fill the rest of the matrix with zeros. Any $k\times k$ minor which is not the upper left $k\times k$ block will be zero because it involves a zero row or zero column. Hence, all $k\times k$ minors of the two matrices will coincide, but they are different because they differ in the upper left $k\times k$ block.